# MySQL Query taking too long when using orderby on large dataset

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to improve the query time on a database that has around 20 million rows in the table:

The following is the query I am running

```
`select DATE(timestamp) as timestamp, count(id) as authentications, count(distinct userid) as unique_users from `logs` where `org_id` = '54' and `timestamp` between '2016-09-14 09:00:00' and '2017-08-21 09:37:59' group by DATE(timestamp) order by `timestamp` asc`
```

The query takes about 20-30 seconds to complete (that particular `org id` has about 6-7million records its going through)

According to the profiler its spending 95% of the time on sorting the result.

I have an index that is being used as well (please see explain below):

1   SIMPLE  logs

```
ref by_org_id_and_timestamp,org_id  by_org_id_and_timestamp 4   const   6231240 Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

Table structure is:

```
id  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment  
org_id  int(11) NO  MUL         
profile varchar(256)    NO              
linehash    varchar(50) NO  UNI         
timestamp   datetime    NO              
userid  varchar(256)    NO              
server_id   varchar(1024)   NO              
access_id   int(11) NO
```

Any ideas as to why its taking so long or is 20-30 seconds the best I am going to get?

Thanks for looking (and hopefully your help!)

------ SHOW CREATE TABLE logs ------

`id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  org_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  profile varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  linehash varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
  userid varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  server_id varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  access_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY logs_linehash_unique (linehash),
  KEY by_org_id_and_timestamp (org_id,timestamp),
  KEY org_id (org_id),
  KEY by_org_id_and_timestamp_userid (org_id,timestamp,userid(255))`

Comment: do you use indexes?

Comment: show your complete table structure via: SHOW CREATE TABLE logs.  As mentioned, it's probably related to a missing key.

Comment: You mentioned SQL Server but `DATE` is not a SQL Server function. The syntax looks like you may be using MySQL. Please update tags accordingly. If you don't know what DBMS you're using, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Dan apologies yes it is MySQL will update the tags accordingly. Thanks, I'll also update the show create table logs shortly Charlie. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Aside from asking about indexes, I would change your "count(id)" to just "count(*)".

I would also have a covering index on your table on...

(org_id, timestamp, userid )

The org_id and timestamp to cover your where criteria.  Having the "userID" along for the ride will help on your count( distinct ), and also having all the pieces in the index, the engine does not have to go to the raw data pages to get any other values.  So it can process your query directly from the index.

Comment: Thanks DRapp, I have added that index (updated the show create table output as well). It unfortunately hasn't made any difference but many thanks for the suggestion. I'm quite new to indexes though so I am not sure if having the other indexes there is essentially slowing down this query and if it would be better to remove them? I also tried a count(*).

Comment: @ChrisAndre, you can get rid of your other two by Org and Org + Timestamp as they are both covered by the same single index here by Org, Timestamp AND User.  The engine does not need to guess at a less-optimum index to be used.

Comment: @ChrisAndre, also, when dealing with aggregates on large tables, it is sometimes better to have pre-aggregate tables, but in your case, you are looking for distinct users over an always possible changing time span.  You may want to look into aggregate summary tables for future impact for your site.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp, I have removed the indexes and am currently running an optmise task on the table as I have been messing with the indexes a alot today then I'll rerun my tests. 

Thanks yes I was thinking about putting it into a task and compiling monthly stats for a historic searches as its unlikely that its needed to go down to a particular week and if they do then I may just have to accept that that task will take 20-30 seconds to complete. I will look into aggregate summary tables though, you have been a great help thank you.

Comment: So @DRapp, optimised the table after adding the indexes and unfrotunatley still the same issues. I have however located the slow down. Whats causing the slow down in the query is actually the distinct count part. The distinct count is causing about an extra 18-20 seconds on the query for the data set I am testing with with the select and the count(*) only taking around 3 seconds. So I am off looking at how to optimise distinct counts now